# Engine ticking, clicking, tapping

Tags: engine, chevrolet, noise, cruze

2013 Chevy Cruze
Just had the water pump and belt changed and now when my car is in idle it makes a clicking noise. It goes away when accelerating and only happens sometimes when car is in park. Think it’s coming from the same belt area like maybe a pulley but not sure what one. Any ideas on what could be wrong making this noise and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It didn't make any of these noises prior to the cam belt change?